# java se kit installated but not showing in pc

Tags: java

I'm pursuing for google android development program courses.
I have no idea which java  se kit will be applicable for my pc. my pc if of 32bit
.I installed javase kit 8u162 windows*84 but I didn't find java in cmd. it is not showing my pc after installing. please kindly give me any solutions

Comment: Please first have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then edit your question and be more specific about your problem. I also flag this question, as it is more suited for superuser.

Comment: To get java in cmd you have to add your java bin directory path to "path" in system variable.

Comment: anything happened whe you type `java -version` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can have below configuration:

```
32-bit OS - 32-bit JDK - 32-bit Eclipse (32-bit only)
64-bit OS - 32-bit JDK - 32-bit Eclipse
64-bit OS - 64-bit JDK - 64bit Eclipse (64-bit only)
```

By default Java is installed at either of the below locations:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java
C:\Program Files\Java
```

For CMD to find your Java, you need to set environment variables (JAVA_HOME & path)